# Theme customization of Inkscape

Tags: user-interface, themes, customization, inkscape

How do I customize my Inkscape theme?  F.e. is there a way to show a 'dark' UI theme?

There doesn't seem to be a setting anywhere for it... I've been through all the settings, views and everything else I could think of.  I'm currently using version 0.92.3.

Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you need to modify or exchange the gtkrc file:
http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Customizing_Inkscape
https://logosbynick.com/how-to-make-inkscape-go-dark/

For Linux, I'm not sure how to achieve usage of a specific theme for a specific application. I'd be interested to learn how that works, though.

Comment: Thanks, @Moini, fantastic resources both!

Comment: Btw. one of our developers is currently working on this for version 1.0, if you have some time, you can cheer him on: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/merge_requests/294